# Input and button not aligned horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm making an email form where people can submit their emails and be part of an email list, in order to do this I have made an **input** and a **button** that go side by side. The issue that I am getting is that even though the button and inputs are the exact same height, and should be aligned horizontally perfectly it instead has a pixel difference with the button being a pixel higher than the input. How can I fix this?

```css
#form {
  display flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.email-form {
  padding: 60px;
  margin-top: 85px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.form input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  outline: 0 none;
}

.form button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #707070;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="" id="email">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" /><button type="submit" class="submit"><p>Sign up</p></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change

```
<p>Sign up</p>
```

To

```
<div>Sign up</div>
```

Or just

```
Sign up
```

It should work.

There's a bunch of margin settings on the `<p>` element that are overflowing and messing up your alignment.

Comment: surely if it was an overflow issue you could use `overflow: hidden` in order to fix it which didn't work when i tested it although removing the **p** tag did the job.

Comment: When I said overflow I meant the margin was making it bigger than it appeared and it was kind of spilling out of it's container. If you inspect a <p> element in chrome you'll see the margins that I'm talking about. i didn't mean css overflow. Perhaps I could have phrased it better.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove p tag around the Sign up text.

```
<button type="submit" class="submit">Sign up</button>
```

```css
#form {
  display flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.email-form {
  padding: 60px;
  margin-top: 85px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.form input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  outline: 0 none;
}

.form button {
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #707070;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form action="" id="email">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <button type="submit" class="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```